# Lebesgue integral on a limited interval

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(R,B(R),m)$ a Lebesgue measurable space on $R$,

$\forall n\in N$ denote: $f_n(x)=arctan(n|x|)$.

Show: $lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{[-1,1]} f_n dm =π$

My trial:

Notice that $f_n$ is a positive inceasing sequence for all $x\neq 0$ and $n\in N$.
So by the convergence monotone theorem of Lebesgue, we get:
Denote: $f(x)=lim_{n\to \infty} f_n = π/2$ so,

$lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{[-1,1]} f_n dm= \int_{[-1,1]} f dm= \int_{[-1,1]} π/2= π$

Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $\arctan (n|x|) \leq \tan (n|x|)$ is not valid.

The result follows immediately from Dominated Convergence Theorem since $\arctan (n|x|) \to \frac  {\pi} 2$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $\arctan $ is a bounded function.

Comment: Can you give more details about how this theorem is relevant to my question (since I did not know it yet).

Comment: I saw your tags and I thought you would know the  basic theorems of measure theory: Monotone Convergence Theorem and Dominated ConvergenecTheorem. These are basic theorems that tell you that you can interchange limits and integrals under very mild conditions. @Maths1999_

Comment: I edited my post, can you take a look @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @Maths1999_ Yes, Monotone Convergence Theorem also works.

Comment: Can I ask how can i explain how arctan(n|x|) is measurable?

Comment: Continuous functions are measurable.